# IrfanView won't remember the last window size/position on exit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, irfanview

I'm using a portable version of IrfanView 4.51 (32-bit) on Windows 7 (Dual Screen) and it won't remember the last window size/position on exit?

The checkbox 'Remember the last window size (on program exit)' is obviously checked.

Is there anything I can try to fix it? Thank you.

**Update:**

I'm sorry I'm afraid my initial question was misleading. I've just noticed that it does start in the right (the last x-y) position! The actual problem is the height of the window. Even though the height value being stored in the .ini file the window height is not kept for the next start.

Comment: Are the configurations of IrfanView in a .ini file and the .ini file is not read-only?

Comment: @Aulis Ronkainen Yes, it uses the .ini file and no it's not read-only. I also tried to run the program from the D drive (just to be sure) and it's the same story. Thank you!

Comment: The config file should have the position stored, in some variable. Can you please check if the config file is changed (and position is correct) as you change the position/size of the window or exit the application?

Comment: @Aulis Ronkainen Yes, it does store the coordinates and height/width under [WinPosition] as well as the Recent Files, but for some weird reason it does not affect the next start at all. Thank you once more!

Comment: @Aulis Ronkainen I'm sorry I'm afraid I was a bit misleading before. I've just noticed that it does start in the right (the last x-y) position! The actual problem is the height of the window. Even though the height value is being stored in the file the window height is not kept for the next start.